# Identify this robot?

Tags: identification

Seen in [this](https://medium.com/@GDurendal/i-created-an-a-i-clone-of-jesus-4263339c327) story, and in * many * others relating to AI and robots (determined via google image search...)

What build is this and it's origin?

[image]

Comment: It appears to be an [image](https://unsplash.com/photos/YKW0JjP7rlU) uploaded to unspash (an online source for free images) on 17 January 2018 by a user named "Franck V".  The info posted with the image includes camera / lens details, but not the model of the robot.

Comment: right...I determined that much :) thanks though @sempaiscuba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The robot is called Alter. It is part of the robot exhibit at the Miraikan museum in Tokio. It seems from [this website](https://www.miraikan.jst.go.jp/en/research/facilities/AndroidALTER/), that it has been created by Ikegami Takashi, specially for the exhibit, in order to explore human interaction by mimicking human poses.

Comment: brilliant - thank you